# Usage of -density switch with the do not enlarge flag for -resize does not work

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I am working on a feature of an image conversion service, and I need to
scale an image - 
 if the requested dimensions are bigger of the original image, it should not enrlage. 
ImageMagick supports that, 
but when I use -density to improve quality of converted image (I convert from pdf to png) , the "do not enlarge" behavior does not work well. 

 examples:

```
Image attributes for /home/yzaslavs/Downloads/drawing.pdf
/home/yzaslavs/Downloads/drawing.pdf PBM 2271x1610 2271x1610+0+0 16-bit Bilevel Gray 457KB 0.000u 0:00.000
Starting conversions.............
convert /home/yzaslavs/Downloads/drawing.pdf -resize 5000x5000\> out.png
out.png PNG 2271x1610 2271x1610+0+0 8-bit sRGB 383KB 0.000u 0:00.000
convert -resize 5000x5000\> -background white -depth 8 -density 160x160 /home/yzaslavs/Downloads/drawing.pdf out.png
out.png PNG 5000x3545 5000x3545+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.943MB 0.000u 0:00.000
-------
convert -background white -depth 8 -density 160x160 -resize 5000x5000\> /home/yzaslavs/Downloads/drawing.pdf out.png
out.png PNG 5000x3545 5000x3545+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.943MB 0.000u 0:00.000
-------
convert -background white /home/yzaslavs/Downloads/drawing.pdf -resize 5000x5000\> out.pn
out.png PNG 2271x1610 2271x1610+0+0 8-bit sRGB 383KB 0.000u 0:00.000
-------
convert -background white -depth 8 /home/yzaslavs/Downloads/drawing.pdf -resize 5000x5000\> out.png
out.png PNG 2271x1610 2271x1610+0+0 8-bit sRGB 383KB 0.000u 0:00.000
-------
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: For PNG, -density does not affect resizing. It only sets the size when printing. It does set pixel dimension for the initial size of the rasterized PDF. The -resize should always come after reading the PDF and the -density should come before reading the PDF. You will get better quality, not larger size, if you use a larger density. But the resize will always size to the size you specify. If you want it not to resize if the species dimensions WxH is larger than the image, then use -resize WxH\<. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry

Comment: I know what density is and the fact it has nothing to do with resizing.  providing \> means - do not enrlage if needs to exceed original image attributes. and this does not work when you specify -density. 
Have a look again at the example I posted, it demonstrates it well.

Comment: If the original dimension provided by identify is for example 500x500 - and i request  1000x1000, I do not want it to get enlarged. 
It all appears in my above examples - these are real executions results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it works with **ImageMagick** v7:

```
# Basic, default density is 72dpi
convert -depth 8 a.pdf -resize 5000x5000\> info:
a.pdf PDF 595x842 595x842+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.000

# I specify density to match default and file comes out the same
convert -depth 8 -density 72 a.pdf -resize 5000x5000\> info:
a.pdf PDF 595x842 595x842+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.000

# I increase the density 10% and image gets 10% bigger - fair enough!
convert -depth 8 -density 80 a.pdf -resize 5000x5000\> info:
a.pdf PDF 661x935 661x935+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.000

# I double the density and the image doubles too - fair enough!
convert -depth 8 -density 144 a.pdf -resize 5000x5000\> info:
a.pdf PDF 1191x1684 1191x1684+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.000

# I quadruple the density and the image quadruples too
convert -depth 8 -density 288 a.pdf -resize 5000x5000\> info:
a.pdf PDF 2381x3368 2381x3368+0+0 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.000

# 8x density and image gets resized now too
convert -depth 8 -density 576 a.pdf -resize 5000x5000\> info:
a.pdf PDF 3535x5000 3535x5000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2.700u 0:02.699

# Still bigger density and image still resized
convert -depth 8 -density 800 a.pdf -resize 5000x5000\> info:
a.pdf PDF 3535x5000 3535x5000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 3.890u 0:03.890
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for running  with running with your example.
Why should density effect the resize in case of "do not enlarge" ?
Can't image magick keep same dimensions with increased density? how did you get the default density for your experiment? I would lke to get default density for mine.

Comment: I  googled and found this -
identify -format "%w x %h %x x %y" image.jpg 

I will update soon.
Thanks!

Comment: identify -format "%w x %h %x x %y" drawing.pdf
1684 x 2384 72 x 72 <BR>
convert -depth 8 -density 160 drawing.pdf[0] drawing.png<BR>
identify drawing.png <BR>
drawing.png PNG 3742x5298 3742x5298+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.36MB 0.000u 0:00.000

Comment: My experiment proves what you wrote.